# Ensure index not working - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to ensure index on a field of a document and its not
working. MongoDB version is 2.0.2.
This is very basic and somehow i'm feeling i might have missed
something or not!!!
Its able to insert 3 docs with same empty string !!

Here are details :

```
> use testinsert
switched to db testinsert
> db.users.ensureIndex({ name : 1});
> doc = {
... name  : ""
... }
{ "name" : "" }
> doc
{ "name" : "" }
> db.users.stats();
{
       "ns" : "testinsert.users",
       "count" : 0,
       "size" : 0,
       "storageSize" : 8192,
       "numExtents" : 1,
       "nindexes" : 2,
       "lastExtentSize" : 8192,
       "paddingFactor" : 1,
       "flags" : 1,
       "totalIndexSize" : 16352,
       "indexSizes" : {
               "_id_" : 8176,
               "name_1" : 8176
       },
       "ok" : 1
}
> db.users.insert(doc);
> db.users.insert(doc);
> db.users.insert(doc);
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1980dc7e154e6702c4914c"), "name" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1980dd7e154e6702c4914d"), "name" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1980dd7e154e6702c4914e"), "name" : "" }
> db.users.ensureIndex({ name : 1});
> db.users.insert(doc);
> db
testinsert
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1980dc7e154e6702c4914c"), "name" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1980dd7e154e6702c4914d"), "name" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1980dd7e154e6702c4914e"), "name" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1981557e154e6702c49150"), "name" : "" }
> version();
version: 2.0.2
```

can somebody pls clarify as to what might be the problem !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are **no** problems, you can see that the index is there. You're expecting it not to allow duplicate elements? For that you have to set unique flag to true:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ name : 1},{unique: true});
```

UPDATE: running ensure once again with `{unique: true}` doesn't work, you have to drop and `ensureIndex` again:

```
db.users.dropIndex({name:1})
db.users.ensureIndex({ name : 1}, {unique:true, dropDups : true});
```

Comment: Damn, beat me by 12 seconds! +1 for you.

Comment: @milan Yeah, I deleted it once I saw you'd beaten me.

Comment: WTH !.. I'm banging my head i missed tht one.. but, i tries it and it still succeeds 
> db.users.ensureIndex({ name : 1}, {unique : true});
> db.users.insert({name : ""});
> db.users.insert({name : ""});

do i need to delete and recreate index ??

Comment: drop and ensure again, db.users.ensureIndex({ name : 1}, {unique:true, dropDups : true});

Comment: Still feeling aweful abt it.. found out one thing .. getting answers in SO is insanely faster than in Mongo google groups