# dropDups true not working mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am using `mongoDB shell with version 3.0.2`
I am trying to ensure uniqueness constraint over a `username` field in collection `users`.

This is what I gave:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({"username": 1},{unique: true})
```

It gave me following error:

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "errmsg" : "exception: E11000 duplicate key error index: mybackend.users.$username_1 dup key: { : \"rahat\" }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Then i used, `dropDups: true` in the command:

```
 db.users.ensureIndex({"username": 1},{unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

Then too I get the same error:

```
 {
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "errmsg" : "exception: E11000 duplicate key error index: mybackend.users.$username_1 dup key: { : \"rahat\" }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

I also saw [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943418/ensure-index-not-working-mongodb) but here it already had one index. Mine does not have one.

`db.users.getIndexes()` ->

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mybackend.users"
    }
]
```

I looked for [this issue on github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/56) and restarted the mongo but to no use. What am I doing wrong? I think I am doing a silly mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The drop duplicates functionality on index creation is no longer supported since Mongo version 3.0. See [the compatibility changes page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#remove-dropdups-option) for the 3.0 release.

Comment: got it. Thanks, this was what I was suspecting could be the reason left for the problem. Since it does not support `dropDups`, is there any other work around or we have to drop the duplicate records manually?

Comment: I am not aware of anything else than a manual work around, sorry.

Comment: Node-js mongodb latest driver unfortunately still shows it on docs http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#createIndex

Comment: A solution can be: making a backup, removing all documents, creating index and recovering documents.